# Prefix local does not match to a namespace in appication root element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have built an application using MEF and  BootStrapper with MVVM model in WPF.

in App.xaml I have following code.

```
 <Application x:Class="My.ClientFramework.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup">
<Application.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/My.Windows.Themes.Light;component /Theme.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/My.ClientFramework.Infrastructure;component/Themes/Theme.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/My.Windows.Themes.Light.Infrastructure;Component/Theme.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>     
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And for some reason the start tag Application root element gets a squiggly line under it and when I hover over it, it says Prefix 'local' does not map to a namespace.

I have spent 6-7 hours to figure out why this is happening but all the that I got after googling is not at all pointing towards my problem. When I don't have anything like x:local then why my Application root element in above Xaml code gets a squiggly line that says prefix local does not map to a namespace, it is literally driving me nuts. All suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you search the entire solution for the string `local`, do you find any matches?

Comment: I have 4 projects in one solution and there is one project where I have something like <local:ModuleResources x:Key ="ToolBarTemplateSelector". But i see no problem over there.

Comment: Sounds like you've found the issue; now just find out what namespace `ModuleResources` lives in, and you can add the prefix mapping.

Comment: remove `ResourceDictionaries` and rebuild your project.
if everything is good, reput them one by one, and see which one has propblem

Comment: @Safi You are right  I commented out ResourceDictionaries and it stopped giving me the error. Though I have to put them back one by one to see where is the actual problem lying, will keep posting.